# Problems reloading fields in a form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am having problems with a reloading fields in special with datepicker in a form.

The site is online on http://eskelak.eus/ and when I try to perform a search in the search form the first time is ok, but when I push reset button before, the datepicker fields is not restoring.

```
function the_search_form() {
global $wpdb;

$firstname = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'first_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$lastname = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'last_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$province = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'province', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$locality = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'locality', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$from = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'from', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$to = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'to', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


if (!empty($locality) && isset($locality)) {
    $locality_row = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare(
        'SELECT * FROM wp_eskelak_locality WHERE id = %s',
        $locality
    ) );
    $province = $locality_row->province;
}


$active = ' class="active"';
?>
<!-- START SEARCH FORM -->
<form method="get" action="/index.php" id="search">
    <?php $lang = get_language_for_link() ?>
    <?php if ($lang == '') : ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="370"/>
    <?php else : ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="372"/>
    <?php endif ?>
    <h3><?php _e('Buscar Eskelas', 'eskelak')?></h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>"
            placeholder="<?php _e( 'Introducir nombre', 'eskelak') ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="province" value="<?php echo isset($province) ? $province : '' ?>"/>
        <button data-filter="true" value="alava"<?php echo $province=='alava'? $active : '' ?>><?php _e('Araba-Álava') ?></button>
        <button data-filter="true" value="guipuzcoa"<?php echo $province=='guipuzcoa'? $active : '' ?>><?php _e('Gipuzkoa') ?></button>
        <button data-filter="true" value="vizcaya"<?php echo $province=='vizcaya'? $active : '' ?>><?php _e('Bizkaia') ?></button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $lastname ?>"
            placeholder="<?php _e( "Introducir apellidos", 'eskelak' ) ?>">
        <?php the_localities() ?><input id="desde" type="text" name="from" data-placeholder="<?php _e('Desde', 'eskelak') ?>" class="datepicker" value="<?php echo $from ?>"
                placeholder="<?php _e('Desde', 'eskelak') ?>"/>
        <input id="hasta" type="text" name="to" data-placeholder="<?php _e('Hasta', 'eskelak') ?>" class="datepicker" value="<?php echo $to ?>"
                placeholder="<?php _e('Hasta', 'eskelak') ?>"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button data-send="enviar" type="submit" style="margin: 3px 8px;float: right;" class="buscar">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/images/icons/search.png" alt="<?php _e('Buscar')?>" />
            <?php _e('Buscar', 'eskelak')?>
        </button>
        <button form="search" data-reset="reset" id="reset_filter" type="submit" style="margin: 3px 8px;float: right;" >
            <!-- <img src="<?php // echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/images/icons/search.png" alt="<?php // _e('Buscar')?>" /> -->
            <?php _e('Reiniciar Filtro', 'eskelak')?>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- END SEARCH FORM -->
<?php}
```

Comment: the quality of the question if very low. If you are asking about jQuery component - then please provide the code snippet related to it, preferably on JSFiddle, so people can help you.

Comment: in your site it is working

Comment: The first time is ok @DipaliVasani but when you perform the second search and you try to load the datapicker again this is empty and it is not loading de calendar.

Comment: Sorry @Farside but I am not sure about where is the bug, in the form, in jquery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the `script` that sets up the `datepicker`

```
<script src="data:text/javascript,(function(%24)%7B%24(%22.datepicker%22).datepicker(%7BshowButtonPanel%3Atrue%2CdateFormat%3A%22dd%2Fmm%2Fyy%22%7D)%3B%7D)(jQuery)%3B" type="text/javascript">(function($){$(".datepicker").datepicker({showButtonPanel:true,dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"});})(jQuery);</script>
```

which in the home page is just after the form, is missing in the second page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your website needs a good update. In Chrome DevTools log I have:

`JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:40 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated
jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:42 console.trace()migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:42
jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:40 JQMIGRATE: 'hover' pseudo-event is deprecated, use 'mouseenter mouseleave'
jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:42 console.trace()migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:42`

As first step, you should get rid of those warning.

Hope will help!

Comment: I will try to upgrade the JQuery libreries @augusto and I will tell you about the result.

Comment: @Augusto, these are just warnings, they don't really make the weather here, they just indicate soon or later you have to update the libraries.